# Install OS X on external drive without rebooting?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-el-capitan

I manage several hundred MacBook pros at a school. There are times when I need to remove the hard drive from a machine, attach it to an enclosure and plug it in to my main machine via USB and erase the drive and reinstall the OS. I hate having to stop working for about 30 minutes while the OS installs externally. I know there are other ways to go about this like creating an image of a fresh install and then restoring the drive with that image, booting up the other machine via recovery partition or network recovery, or just using another machine that isn't mine all together. I already use deploy studio, net boots, and other methods as the primary deployment method, I'm just curious about this specific rebooting installation. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than post as an answer just for the beginnings of an idea - what about imaging one machine with something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) once installed but before first run [or after, if you want them set up with specific account structures, but identical]; then booting the future target machines to [Target Disk mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH10725) & simply cloning that fresh image back over the old install ? CCC is perfectly capable of running in the background, so your other work can continue as normal.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to run the OS X installer without rebooting. For security and quality reasons, the OS X installer is designed to only run when booted from the clean, stripped-down, locked-down OS X image that it is packaged in.

If you could run the OS X installer from just whatever lived-in, modified, possibly malware- or hacker-compromised version of OS X you had already booted into on your machine, then it would be fairly easy for something in that already-booted OS environment to interfere with the proper functioning of the install process, resulting in a failed, damaged/corrupted, or compromised install.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the dd command to create an image that you can flash. Be careful though, this command is commonly referred to as data destroyer. This essentially creates an image of the drive, and then can be transferred directly to another drive, or to a file. Same thing with flashing.

Comment: I feel like he covered in his question that he wasn't interested in this kind of solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I finally broke down after I posted this and created an image of a clean install with most of the installs I would do after a fresh install. It's on a partition on one of my SSD's and using terminal it took 11 minutes to restore a drive with this image, all the while I was coding, photoshopping, and not leaving my desk. Really I suppose It boiled down to me being lazy. I always have to fix a drive when I least want to. I had some free time and I figured why not just do it and make the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can install an OSX image onto an external drive, then boot the malfunctioning MBP from the external drive using the Option key at boot time. Once booted to the external drive, you can perform whatever maintenance you want to on the machine in a standalone fashion. No removing drives, no shutting down your primary workstation.

Comment: I feel like he covered in his question that he wasn't interested in this kind of solution.

Comment: JTM wants a solution that doesn't use Recovery Mode, a separate machine, Deploy Studio, or interupt his work on his primary machine. My solution provides that. If JTM would like to provide more info, we can work on more solutions. To add something of substance, CarbonCopyCloner is my prefered method of performing a standalone imaging.